# swift: wait until power source has changed (mac)

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, iokit

So far I have the code snippet:
`charging = IOPSGetTimeRemainingEstimate().isEqual(to: kIOPSTimeRemainingUnlimited)`, which returns true or false depending on whether the computer is charging or not. I want to monitor this value for updates so that it runs a script on change. I am new to Swift and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the charging state with:

```
import IOKit.ps

let info = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo().takeRetainedValue()
let sources = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesList(info).takeRetainedValue() as [CFTypeRef]
if let batterySource = sources.first {
    let pSource = IOPSGetPowerSourceDescription(info, batterySource).takeUnretainedValue() as NSDictionary
    let isCharging = pSource[kIOPSIsChargingKey] as! Int // 1 = charging, 0 = not charging
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear, but I want to monitor this value for changes. I want to be able to run a function when it changes. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: *Monitoring* can be also a simple timer. However there is an API `IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource` to register for a notification about changes